# React Native ViewPagerAndroid with multiple visible pages

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to use ViewPagerAndroid to show a carousel with "stops" at each item like so:

[image: carousel]

It appears react-native-carousel and react-native-swiper don't support these features yet on Android. I have a native ViewPager that does what I need it to do, but I'm having problems incorporating it into the React Native environment.

The native component CarouselContainer uses layout.xml and expects a ViewPager subcomponent.

```
     <com.mycompany.ui.CarouselContainer
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </com.mycompany.ui.CarouselContainer >
```

CarouselContainer is a FrameLayout subclass that gets a ref to the ViewPager in its `onFinishInflate` method. It calls `setPageMargin` on the ViewPager and `setClipChildren(false)` to render multiple ViewPager pages on the screen at the same time.

I took a look at the ViewPagerAndroid implementation, and it looks like it's basically a ViewPager set up by [ReactViewPagerManager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/viewpager/ReactViewPagerManager.java). The ReactViewPagerManager exposes the ViewPager's child views via the `ViewGroupManager` interface.

So I copied `ReactViewPagerManager` in my own `CarouselViewPagerManager` and `ReactViewPager` into `CarouselViewPager`.

The one thing new here is `CarouselViewPagerContainer`. The manager creates the container and the container creates the view pager instead of the manager creating the view pager directly. Since there's no layout xml the container instantiates the pager directly instead of getting it from `onFinishInflate`.

For some reason, I'm getting nothing rendered on the screen when I use it. I think it's due to having the CarouselViewPagerContainer view in between but I'm not sure where to even begin. Do I need to mess with `LayoutShadowNode`? Do I need to add the CarouselViewPager itself to the list of child views returned by the manager?

The [Native UI Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html#content) documentation only mentions SimpleViewManager. :(

```
// Copy of ReactViewPagerManager
public class CarouselViewPagerManager extends ViewGroupManager<CarouselViewPagerContainer> {

    @Override
    protected CarouselViewPagerContainer createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new CarouselViewPagerContainer(reactContext);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void addView(CarouselViewPagerContainer parent, View child, int index) {
        parent.addViewToAdapter(child, index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(CarouselViewPagerContainer parent) {
        // Should the CarouselViewPager be also counted?
        return parent.getViewCountInAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildAt(CarouselViewPagerContainer parent, int index) {
        return parent.getViewFromAdapter(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeViewAt(CarouselViewPagerContainer parent, int index) {
        parent.removeViewFromAdapter(index);
    }

}


public class CarouselViewPagerContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final CarouselViewPager mPager; // Copy of ReactViewPager

    public CarouselViewPagerContainer(ReactContext context) {
        mPager = new CarouselViewPager(context);
    }

    // ...

    // Pass through to the CarouselViewPager
    public void setCurrentItemFromJs(int item, boolean animated) {
        mPager.setCurrentItemFromJs(item, animated);
    }

    /*package*/ void addViewToAdapter(View child, int index) {
        mPager.addViewToAdapter(child, index);
    }

    /*package*/ void removeViewFromAdapter(int index) {
        mPager.removeViewFromAdapter(index);
    }

    /*package*/ int getViewCountInAdapter() {
        return mPager.getViewCountInAdapter();
    }

    /*package*/ View getViewFromAdapter(int index) {
        return mPager.getViewFromAdapter(index);
    }
}
```

If you know of a simpler way to tackle this problem I'm all ears!

I mean the only thing I'm using the FrameLayout container for is to center the first Viewpager page and occupy space so multiple pages show.  :/

It's been such a struggle :(